# Bloom Filter C implementation

Tags: algorithm, c, bloom-filter

this is my first C program. It creates a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) from an array of `N` char arrays and `k` hash functions.

I'm not particularly concerned about maximum performance at this point, as I'm just starting with C. Any suggestions on making my code more idiomatic would be highly appreciated.

````
// Bloomfilter.c
#include <stdio.h>

// Function headers
int modularHash(char string[], int R, int M);
int sh1(char string[]);
int sh2(char string[]);
int sh3(char string[]);

int main()
{
    enum
    {
        N = 3,  // the number of strings
        M = 10, // the size of the bloom filter
        k = 3,  // the number of hash functions
    };

    char *strings[N] = {"abc", "777", "xyz"};

    int bloom_filter[M] = {0}; // array of `n` 0s.

    // array of pointers to hash functions.
    int (*hashers[k])() = {sh1, sh2, sh3};

    // Fill the bloom filter
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            {
                // Compute the hash of string j using the k'th hash function
                // Map the hash to a position in the bloom filter
                // then add this position to the bloom filter.
                int result = hashers[i](strings[j]);
                int position = result % M;
                bloom_filter[position] = 1;
            }
        }

    // Print the bloom filter
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        printf("%d ", bloom_filter[i]);


    // TODO implement a function for checking a string against the bloom filter.
    return 0;
}

/*
 Compute the modular hash of a char array
    @param string, array of characters to hash
    @param R: a seed value, should be a prime
    @param M: a seed value, should also be a prime
*/
int modularHash(char string[], int R, int M)
{
    int chars = 3; // the number of characters
    int hash = 0;

    char s;
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars - 1; i++)
        s = string[i];
    n = (int)s;
    hash = (R * hash + n) % M;
    return hash;
}

int sh1(char string[])
{
    int M = 3;
    int R = 31;
    return modularHash(string, M, R);
}

int sh2(char string[])
{
    int M = 47;
    int R = 17;
    return modularHash(string, M, R);
}

int sh3(char string[])
{
    int M = 97;
    int R = 29;
    return modularHash(string, M, R);
}

```
````

Comment: My thoughts: (1) ALWAYS use the braces with each `for` (and also `if`).   (2) possibly related to that, what is this doing: `for (int i = 0; i < chars - 1; i++) s = string[i];` ?  (3) simple is good, but function pointers are inherently complex;  instead of function pointers, could you have an array of M and R values (is there some sort of Pair class available) ?

Comment: Should the description of `@param M` read *The modulus*? The loop in `modularHash()` looks strange for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Questionable code**

Why assign `s` multiple times?

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars - 1; i++)
    s = string[i];
```

Above is same as

```
s = string[chars - 1 - 1];
```

Instead of one `%` operation after the loop `(R * hash + n) % M`, I'd expect that in the loop.

**`%` is [not mod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)**

`modularHash()` returns values in the `(-M ... M)` range, not `[0 ... M)` as `char` may be *signed*.

Consider the UB caused when `result < 0`.

```
int result = hashers[i](strings[j]);
int position = result % M;
bloom_filter[position] = 1;  // UB
```

Instead, use *unsigned* math.

```
unsigned modularHash(char string[], unsigned R, unsigned M) {
  unsigned char *ustring = (unsigned char *) string; 
  ...
  unsigned hash = 0;
  ...
    s = ustring[i];
```

**Avoid signed overflow**

`R * hash + n`, with `int` math, may overflow with large `R` leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Does not apply with *this* code given the modest constants.

**Use `const`**

In functions that do not alter referenced data, use `const`.  This allows for wider function application, self-documents code's usage and allows select optimization not allows otherwise seen by a compiler.

```
// int modularHash(char string[], int R, int M)
int modularHash(const char string[], int R, int M)
```

**Avoid hard coded limits**

Rather than 3 (an undescribed magic number), consider iterating to end of the string.

```
unsigned modularHash(const char string[], unsigned char R, unsigned char M) {
  const unsigned char *ustring = (const unsigned char *) string; 
  unsigned hash = 0;

  while (*ustring) {
    hash = (R*hash + *ustring) % M;
  }
  return hash;
}
```

If looking to limit up to 3, use more descriptive names and consider a string may be shorter than 3.

```
  int limit = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < limit && *ustring; i++) {
    hash = (R*hash + *ustring) % M;
  }
```

**Avoid defining twice**

Below defines the number of strings twice, once with 3 and once with initializers.

```
    N = 3,  // the number of strings
char *strings[N] = {"abc", "777", "xyz"};
```

Consider below, where the string size is only defined by the number of initializers.

```
char *strings[] = {"abc", "777", "xyz"};
size_t N = sizeof strings / sizeof strings[0];
```

Likewise for `hashers[]`.

**Unclear code**

Why -1 in `for (int i = 0; i < chars - 1; i++)`?